# In Google Sheets - creating a link in one cell that combines information from two cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google sheets, I am trying to populate one cell with a link that is created from two different cells. So, for example: A1 contains the text "Google", A2 contains the link "www.google.com", I would like for A3 to automatically contain the text "Google" while being hyperlinked to "www.google.com".

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Google scripts. (Click on Menu | Tools | Script Editor).

Also, to run this example, set the value of the following:

```
Cell A8: Google
Cell B8: https://www.google.com
```

Sample Code:

```
function createHyperLink () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cellContainingText = sheet.getRange("A8:A8");
  var cellContainingLink = sheet.getRange("B8:B8");
  var textWithLink = '=HYPERLINK("' + cellContainingLink.getValue() + '", "'+ cellContainingText.getValue() + '")';
  var cellToModify = sheet.getRange("C8:C8");
  cellToModify.setValue(textWithLink);
}
```

Assume that your text value is in cell `A8` and your corresponding hyperlink is in cell `B8`. Get those values and set the value of cell `C8` to a hyperlink with the values derived from A8 and B8.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! To take this one step further, I am using this in a Google Forms submission spreadsheet. The form would collect Text value and Hyperlink. Is there a way to have this same outcome automatically applied to form submissions?

Comment: You are probably looking at `onFormSubmit()` which triggers a method when the form is submitted. Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()

Answer (score 0):

No need for Apps Script!

You can simply use the HYPERLINK formula like this:

- A1 "Google"
- B1 "http://google.com"
- C1 `=HYPERLINK(B1,A1)`

Comment: Thanks for this but I am looking for this to be automated with form submissions. For example, a form submission would populate "Google" with one question, "www.google.com" in another question, and then the third cell would be automatically populated with the hyperlinked text.